# Using a function to create a function in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm new to programming and I'm interested in if it's possible to use a function to create another function based in inputted information:

```
def get_new_toy(self):
    new_toy = gui.multenterbox(
        msg = 'Enter the data for the new toy:',
        title = 'New Toy',
        fields = ('Toy Name', 'Fun for 0 to 5', 'Fun for 5 to 7', 'Fun for 7 to 10', 'Fun for over 10'))
    method = getattr(PotatoHead, new_toy[0])
    def method(self):
```

I don't think that I'm doing this right

Thankful for any help

---Edit---

Sorry for not making it clear:

I'm creating a virtual pet sort of game for my younger sister.

The 'PotatoHead' can 'play' with certain toys as dictated by functions such as this:

```
   def play_Softball(self):
        self.happiness_num = float(self.happiness)
        if float(self.age) <= 3.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + 0.3
        elif float(self.age) > 3.0 and float(self.age) < 4.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + 0.7
        elif float(self.age) > 4.0 and float(self.age) < 7.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + 1.0
        elif float(self.age) > 7.0 and float(self.age) < 9.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + 0.5
        elif float(self.age) > 9.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + 0.02
            gui.msgbox(
                msg = 'This toy is Only providing minimal fun to your potato head. Either get a new one or play with another!',
                title = 'WARNING!',
                ok_button = 'Understood')
        self.happiness = str(self.happiness_num)
```

I want there to be a function that allows the creation of a new 'toy' as a function that is similar to the one above.

Again, thanks for any help

---UPDATE---

Thanks again, but just wondering

Is it possible to work something such as this into it:

```
'play_' + new_toy[0] = myPotatoHead.create_toy(new_toy[1], new_toy[2], new_toy[3], new_toy[4], new_toy[5])
```

in this context:

```
    def get_new_toy(self):
        new_toy = gui.multenterbox(
            msg = 'Enter the data for the new toy:',
            title = 'New Toy',
            fields = ('Toy Name', 'Fun for 0 to 3', 'Fun for 3 to 4', 'Fun for 4 to 7', 'Fun for 7 to 9', 'Fun for over 9'))
        'play_' + new_toy[0] = myPotatoHead.create_toy(new_toy[1], new_toy[2], new_toy[3], new_toy[4], new_toy[5])
        self.toys.append(new_toy[0])
```

thanks again for any help

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is here.  What do you want your newly created function to do?  You can definitely create (and return) a new function from a python function.

Comment: You may also want to look at making each toy a class rather than a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example python function that returns a new function based on the parameter passed in.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do but this might help  point you in the right direction.

```
def add_to(amount):
    def f(x):
        return x + amount
    return f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_2 = add_to(2)
    add_3 = add_to(3)

    print add_2(42)
    print add_3(42)
```

Given your toy example (which seems like a fun thing to do for you sister) you might try something like this (I haven't tested the code, but it should help out):

```
def create_toy(self, fun_0_3, fun_3_4, fun_4_7, fun_7_9, fun_9_plus):
    def toy(self):
        self.happiness_num = float(self.happiness)
        if float(self.age) <= 3.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + fun_0_3
        elif float(self.age) > 3.0 and float(self.age) < 4.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + fun_3_4
        elif float(self.age) > 4.0 and float(self.age) < 7.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + fun_4_7
        elif float(self.age) > 7.0 and float(self.age) < 9.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + fun_7_9
        elif float(self.age) > 9.0:
            self.happiness_num = self.happiness_num + fun_9_plus
            gui.msgbox(
                msg = 'This toy is Only providing minimal fun to your potato head. Either get a new one or play with another!',
                title = 'WARNING!',
                ok_button = 'Understood')
        self.happiness = str(self.happiness_num)
    return toy

#somewhere else
play_Softball = create_toy(0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 0.5, 0.02)
```